# Community forum and resources for Ubuntu tablet

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, bq, ubuntu-forums

I just unwrapped my brand new BQ Ubuntu tablet, keen to find out what it can do.
At first sight the interface is not really telling me where to find things, how to quickly lauch and stop apps. But I find out little by little. 
In the meantime, if anyone knows **where to find manuals or introductions**, don't hesitate to point me to it ;)

Some things don't seem to work yet. The "Home" app (is that what it's called ?) does not rotate. Xchat does not give me a keyboard, Wikipedia exists only in English ...
As I am knew to the Ubuntu community I don't know yet where to talk about or report those things... is this forum the right place or **is there a dedicated tablet user community**?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Please visit the [help center](http://askubuntu.com/help). Then edit your post so that it would look like a question, which then can be answered.

Comment: If you're looking for general sharing and chat, check out the appropriate subforums of http://UbuntuForums.org . They do have a Ubuntu Tablet and Phone subforum. This site tends to be more Q&A-based.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I guess the Forums are the right place for me to start :)  Will be back here when QA compatible ...

Answer (score 1):

The main resources I am aware of are the following:

- The [Ubuntu Touch Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch) for general (mostly technical) information
- The [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) for discussion (especially the "Ubuntu Phone and Tablet" category)
- The [Ubuntu Touch Google+ Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/118436859239534473331) (with several active Canonical developers)
- And of course [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) with the `ubuntu-touch`, `tablet`, `m10` and related labels when you have specific questions.

Feel free to edit this answer to add other relevant resources.